# How to display millions of images in one webpage like app.thefacesoffacebook.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, image, frontend

I'm inspired by app.thefacesoffacebook.com and would like to build similar thing with Yammer (kind of social network) profiles for my organization.

I have already scraped the data I required like profile id, image URL and others in stored in the data base. But how to display the images in the webpage  like app.thefacesoffacebook.com? Is it normally getting the URLs from DB and displaying images with IMG tag or any other trick they are using. I'm expecting to see the similar behaviour when you click on one image it should zoomin. I'm not really sure about to go about this, any ideas would be helpful. I hope information is enough to guide me, let me know if this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question whose answer would really be immense, but from a bird's eye view, the most common way to implement this would be to employ pagination.

**Pagination** is a "lazy loading" scheme in which groups of images are loaded in predefined amounts.  For instance, you may see a group of 20 images onscreen, but when you scroll to the bottom of those 20 images, an event is fired and the next 20 images are loaded and appended to the window.

If you can imagine in the olden days, before dynamic html, you would have had separate "pages" for each "chunk" of images.  To see the next 20 images, you would click "next".  Modern implementations are not much different in practice, only that they use JavaScript to asynchronously load each chunk automatically, and append it to the current page.

A small, abstract example might be as follows:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var i = 0;
    if ( scrolledToBottom() ) {
        i++;
        loadNextImageGroup(i);
    }
})
```

For more information on pagination and pagination techniques, check your favorite search engine for "pagination tutorials".